# Writing a Python script to ping a list of IP addresses and return whether the host is UP or DOWN and it's just printing my IPs

Tags: python, networking, ping

I've written my script to ping a list of IP addresses in a list. However, when I run the script, it just prints all of my IP addresses, but doesn't actually ping them from what I can tell.

Anyone that could tell me what I'm missing, I'd be most appreciative.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

ip_list = ['8.8.8.8'
'8.8.4.4'
'1.1.1.1'
'4.4.4.4']
for ip in ip_list:
    response = os.popen(f"ping {ip}").read()
    if "Received = 4" in response:
        print(f"UP {ip} Ping Successful, Host is UP!")
    else:
        print(f"DOWN {ip} Ping Unsuccessful, Host is DOWN.")
```

I reworked the code as follows, but it's still not liking something I'm doing. I'm running in a bash shell on macOS.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

ip_list = ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4', '1.1.1.1']
for ip in ip_list:
    p = subprocess.run(['ping '+ip])
    p.wait()
    if p.poll():
        print (ip+" is down")
    else:
        print (ip+" is up")
```

The output I'm getting from that code is here:

```
matt$ python3 Python_Ping_Public3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matt/Desktop/Python_Ping_Public3.py", line 7, in <module>
    p = subprocess.run(['ping '+ip])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ping 8.8.8.8'
```

Comment: did you mean to add commas `,` between the list elements? right now, looks like the `ip_list` only has one element in it.

Comment: Clarification is needed. So it's printing _just_ the IP addresses and _nothing_ else? Or is it printing "Ping Unsuccessful" messages? You should just share the output here, that would be far less ambiguous. Is this even your real code that you're running? If you ran this actual code you'd just get an error, surely, since your "list" of IPs is not defined correctly (no commas).

Comment: The specific issue here is you forgot commas, but Python considers what you think are 4 strings in a list as a single string in a list, spread over 4 lines.

Comment: BTW, using `os.popen()` is not a good practice in new code -- it's still there for backwards compatibility, but the the `subprocess` module is far more capable and lends itself to usage with less security bugs. If your current code was told to ping the IP address `$(rm -rf ~)`, you would have a very bad day; if you were running `subprocess.run(["ping", ip])`, by contrast, that risk wouldn't exist.

Comment: Hosts are not obligated to respond to a ping request, and that has been the default for the Windows firewall (at least for some versions of Windows).

Comment: Thank you all. My apologies for the delay. I had been taking care of my Dad for a few days while he was ill. Yes, I did make a noob mistake of not adding commas in my list. I now see why Python thought it was not separate elements in the list. Thank you for that suggestion @CharlesDuffy

Comment: I've re-worked this a bit using the above suggestions. I might add that I'm running in a bash shell on macOS. It still seems to not like something I'm doing here. Forgive my noob-ness. Just trying to learn as a beginner with something tangible I'm familiar with to build my understanding. I'm using the following code and will post the output I'm seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
letters = ['A'
'B'
'C']
print(letters)
```

This prints `ABC` because the three literals don't have commas between them.

This makes more sense:

```
letters = ['A',
'B',
'C']
print(letters)
```

Whitespace is meaningful in Python, but line endings don't take the place of list separators, that's still a `,`.

This is clearer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

ip_list = ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4', '1.1.1.1', '4.4.4.4']
for ip in ip_list:
    response = os.popen(f"ping {ip}").read()
    if "Received = 4" in response:
        print(f"UP {ip} Ping Successful, Host is UP!")
    else:
        print(f"DOWN {ip} Ping Unsuccessful, Host is DOWN.")
```

Comment: I posted the code above in comments as I reworked it, however it's not liking something I'm doing.

Comment: I've given it some thought, but I can't imagine how you could have been more vague. How is it "not liking something [you're] doing"? Please look at the required syntax in the documentation. You need to *either* pass it a list like `['ping', '8.8.8.8']` *or* a string like `'ping 8.8.8.8'`, but you're passing it a list that has that whole string. Programming is not  just about coming up with cool ideas to make things, it's mostly about excruciating attention to detail, and - I'm sorry to say - a lot of rtfm. (read the friendly manual)